# Passing unsigned char pointer from matlab to c interface dll

Tags: c, matlab, pointers, dll

I have a c interface dll with a c++ class that has an unsigned char pointer function parameter. How do I deal with an unsigned char pointer going from matlab to a c dll? I have tried casting to uint8, libpointer('uint8',0), and just letting matlab handle it, by passing in a number 0, or 1. Nothing I try works. I just get the same input, out of the matlab function that I put into it. Any suggestions on how to deal with unsigned char pointer from matlab to c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody runs into this issue themselves. When you have unsigned char data in c, or c++ that you need to do processing on, the solution is to pass matlab data in as an integer (int). And then receive it through a c interface as an integer and cast it to an unsigned char only after it has been received.

The reason this works is because an integer reserves more memory than an unsigned char. Thus, if you use an integer to pass the data, you will only chop off the extra bit of memory when you assign it to an unsigned char.